# Codelite compiling error

Tags: compiler-construction, codelite

Whenever I run a program in codelite, I get the following error 'Debugger exited with the following error string: "No executable specified, use 'target.exec'.". I've had several compiler errors with other C IDEs like codeblocks as well but whenever I download an IDE I seem to just run into more problems!

Please help, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means one of the 2:

1. You did not specify which executable to debug. You can do this from the Project Settings -> Common Settings -> General, under the "Program to Debug / Run" select your executable
2. You *did* specify an executable, however, it does not exist. In this case, make sure you have compiled your project and that it compiled successfully

You mentioned that you have compiler errors, well, try and get them fixed otherwise the linker will not create the executable.

You should also note that codelite is not a compiler nor codeblocks they are both IDEs, they simply display the output that the compiler produces

Eran

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem and my hours of research has led me to this answer:

The Debugger only runs if there are no spaces in your path to your file ie:

C:\Users\Name\Desktop\files

if however u have something like this

D:\Name\Folder 1\Folder 2\files

Then the debugger doesn't work.

==============================

So the solution is to use a file path that has no spaces and the debugger works perfectly.